# Can PHP trigger an event on a remote Windows Server

Tags: php, windows-server-2016

Is there a way for PHP to send a signal to a Windows Server to run a script?

I am writing a web application which generates database entries that are later synced by a program on a remote Windows Server.  PHP & mySQL are running on AWS. 
The application on the windows server syncs the mySql database with Quickbooks.  Ideally I would like to send a signal from PHP so that if PHP has updated the database, letting the remote Windows server know which script to run to in order to initiate the sync program.  I would need to be pointed in the right direction both on the PHP commands as well as how to setup the listening service on Windows.

I was thinking if I could get Windows to listen on a specific port for a short XML file, PHP could send a password and entity ID number to identify which script to run.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: the windows machine could check the db every X minutes for changes

Answer (score 0):

You can use php on both end. Just install php server on windows, then when request happened execute a windows command. Php can do that.

Answer (score 0):

I would schedule a task to read a specific file from the windows server side and from the php side you could use cron jobs. This question is too broad though and there are several approaches to that. You need to be more "code" specific.